# Android emulator on AMD Ryzen 5 2500u

Tags: windows, android-virtual-device, processor, amd-processor

When I try to start AVD form Android Studio it says my processor doesn't support VT-x or SVM.
I use a Lenovo Thinkpad with an AMD Ryzen 5 2500u Processor (Windows 10 Pro). 
Does this even support SVM?
How can I run AVD on an AMD?

I use the latest versions of all of my programs and systems.

Comment: check in the tech specs if the CPU suppotrs `VT-x or SVM`, and check if it is enabled in BIOS

Comment: I have faced with same issue. The issue occurs if the Virtual Device image is x86(32/64bit) ABI. So i just create the AVD with  ARM  ABI image

Comment: Already tried to create AVD with ARM ABI but thats also no working. Same problem

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Enable SVM in bios and then https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048046/5522344