# Android Studio Emulator AMD Ryzen 5 not working

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, amd-processor

I try to run an emulator after making so many configuration to work with an AMD cpu, I have a windows 10, already disabled Hyper-V and disabled Windows Hypervisor Platform, enabled Virtualization on bios, installed SDK tools on in SDK Manager, and even change graphics emulator to Hardware-GLES 2.0.

Finally, I can effectively had an emulator launches, but my flutter app is not installed.
I wanted to have a stacktrace so I run my emulator with command line and first of all, I have something like this :

```
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
GVM is operational
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
emulator: INFO: boot completed
emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
```

After searches, I added an empty qemu.conf file at C:/
Then :

```
C:\Users\lucil\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:/qemu.conf:1: no group defined
```

In event log I have this stuff : 
[image]

Could someone help me please ? I need to run on emulator because I need to make a presentation (it works well on my android device also)

Comment: I do not understand why my "hello" is not taken into account at the beginning of my post...

Comment: Don't post text as image

Comment: Hi! I have had a similar issue when I transferred to AMD Ryzen 5 3600. The very first thing you need to do is to **ENABLE** `Windows Hypervisor Platform`. What motherboard do you have? Have you tried reinstalling Android Studio? 
Second, make sure in Android SDK `Android SDK Build-Tools 30-rc4` are fully installed (a checkmark not minus) and `Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer)` is installed as well, and `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` is disabled.

Comment: Indeed enable Windows Hypervisor Platform solve the error messages. 
But I still have message relative to qemu.conf missing file, and unfortunately, emulator launches but app is not installed on it.
I have all the required SDK tools you mentionned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048046/5522344