# AMD processor is not launchig android emulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio, amd-processor

my android emulator is stack when I  try to open or run any react-native app in it
please guys help me to fix it

Comment: Welcome.
Please provide logs or pictures that help people get clues about the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048046/5522344